# Is it possible to add environment variables to a tsconfig.json file?

Tags: typescript, environment-variables, development-environment, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths

I have a tsconfig.json file
containing

```
{
  "extends": "../../zlux-app-manager/virtual-desktop/plugin-config/tsconfig.base.json",
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "../../zlux-platform/interface/src/mvd-hosting.d.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

I want to replace **../../** with an environment variable.
What are the possible solutions?

Answer (score 1):

`tsconfig.json` is a simple JSON document lacking any way to refer to environment variables. You can check all possible options in the [tsconfig Schema](http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig).

This does not restrict your use-case though. You can use a data templating language such as [Jsonnet](https://jsonnet.org/). It is a 20% project that can generate dynamic json (or other notation formats). You can use it to generate secondary tsconfig.json file and pass it as arguments to tsc.

Or

Just use Python/JS/Any programming language. At the end of the day you need to produce a `json file` to `tsc`, generate it! The following Python code with the below script runs perfectly.

```
import os, json
r ={
  "extends": os.environ['FOO'] + "/zlux-app-manager/virtual-desktop/plugin-config/tsconfig.base.json",
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    os.environ['FOO'] + "/zlux-platform/interface/src/mvd-hosting.d.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": True
  }
}
print(json.dumps(r))
```

Bash Command

```
$ FOO=mydir python3 tsconfig.py > tsconfig.json && tsc tsconfig.json
```

Comment: Side Note: If you wouldn't have been using env variable in `extends`, the other option with you was going ahead with splitting tsc command as mentioned here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32323#issuecomment-510013098